# .NET 6 WebApi Error using Visual Studio 2022 Current

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

Using .NET 6 and Visual Studio 2022 Current, and I'm getting the error when I try to test the API in Swagger. Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate. also, get the error when I ad the service like add all like the builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataAcess,DataAcess>();

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: WebApi.Utilities.IDataAcess Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: WebApi.Utilities.DataAcess': Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApi.Utilities.DBAccess' while attempting to activate 'WebApi.Utilities.DataAcess'.)'

When I run the app, I get the error as in the image.

[image]

I'm so sure what the issue is, but whenever I try adding the services in .Net 5 or below, it works perfectly fine.

**Controler**

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using WebApi.Models;
    using WebApi.Utilities;
    
    namespace WebApi.Controllers
    {
        [ApiController]
        [Route("analysis")]
        public class analysisDataController : ControllerBase
        {
            private IDataAcess _dataAcess;
            public analysisDataController(IDataAcess dataAcess)
            {
                _dataAcess = dataAcess;
            }
    
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Clients>> getAllClients()
            {
                return _dataAcess.getClients().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    
    namespace WebApi.Models
    {
        public class Clients
        {
            [Required]
            public Guid id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string usercode { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public int clientid { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string clientName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public int searchId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string searchName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**Data Access**

```
    using WebApi.Models;
    
    namespace WebApi.Utilities
    {
        public class DataAcess : IDataAcess
        {
            IDBAccess _dbAccess;
            public DataAcess(DBAccess dBAccess)
            {
                _dbAccess = dBAccess;
            }
    
            public List<Clients> getClient(string user)
            {
                string query = @"SELECT u.UserID AS USER, uc.clientID AS clientID, cl.Name AS clientName,search.ID AS searchID, search.Description AS searchName 
                                     FROM testdb1.user_client AS uc
                                    JOIN testdb2.client AS cl ON uc.clientID = cl.ID
                                    JOIN testdb1.user AS u ON u.ID = uc.userID
                                     JOIN testdb2.set ON set.IDClient = uc.clientID
                                    JOIN testdb2.search ON search.IDSet = set.ID
                                     WHERE u.UserID = '" + user + "'";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
                {
                    var clientData = _dbAccess.RunQuery<Clients>(query);
    
                    return clientData.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
    
            public IEnumerable<Clients> getClients()
            {
                string query = @"SELECT u.UserID AS USER, uc.clientID AS clientID, cl.Name AS clientName,search.ID AS searchID, search.Description AS searchName 
                                     FROM testedb1.user_client AS uc
                                    JOIN testdb1.client AS cl ON uc.clientID = cl.ID
                                    JOIN testdb1.user AS u ON u.ID = uc.userID
                                     JOIN testdb2.set ON set.IDClient = uc.clientID
                                    JOIN testdb2.search ON search.IDSet = set.ID";
    
                var clients = _dbAccess.RunQuery<Clients>(query);
                if(clients.Count != 0)
                    return clients;
    
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**DBAccess Class**

```
    using Dapper;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    
    namespace WebApi.Utilities
    {
        public class DBAccess : IDBAccess
        {
            ILogger _logger;
    
            public DBAccess(ILogger logger)
            {
                _logger = logger;
            }
            public List<T> RunQuery<T>(string query)
            {
                try
                {
                    const string conStr = @"server='####';userid='Aubz';password='Test';database='testdb1.clients'";
                    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conStr))
                    {
                        return conn.Query<T>(query).ToList();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _logger.log(e.Message);
                    throw e;
                }
    
            }
        }
    }
```

**Logger Class**

```
        namespace WebApi.Utilities
        {
        public class Logger : ILogger
        {
            public void log(string logData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(logData);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Interface class IDataAcess**

```
    using WebApi.Models;
    
    namespace WebApi.Utilities
    {
        public interface IDataAcess
        {
            List<Clients> getClient(string user);
            IEnumerable<Clients> getClients();
        }
    }
```

**Interface IDBAccess**

```
    namespace WebApi.Utilities
    {
        public interface IDBAccess
        {
            List<T> RunQuery<T>(string query);
        }
    }
```

**Interface Ilogger**

```
    namespace WebApi.Utilities
    {
        public interface ILogger
        {
            void log(string logData);
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
    using WebApi.Utilities;
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Add services to the container.
    
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllers();
    
  app.Run();
```

Comment: This is not a VS 2022 issue, or even any visual studio issue, you have simply not registered the service. Possible something like `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataAcess,DataAcess>()`. Though you really should look up how to use Dependency injection

Comment: I did add the builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataAcess,DataAcess>();  at the begining like we use it in .NET 5 but I get the error below:                                                                         System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: WebApi.Utilities.IDataAcess Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: WebApi.Utilities.DataAcess': Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApi.Utilities.DBAccess' while attempting to activate 'WebApi.Utilities.DataAcess'.)'

Comment: According to the error, it's not `DataAcess` you need to register, but `DBAccess`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't configure the [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) Container

1. Your controller depend on `IDataAcess` but you don't provide any concrete implementation for it, Add the `DataAcess` as concert implementation in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataAcess,DataAcess>();
```

2. `DataAcess` is depended on the concrete `DBAccess` and store it as `IDBAccess`, this is pointless your class should depend on Interface not on concrete

```
IDBAccess _dbAccess;
public DataAcess(IDBAccess dBAccess)  //<<< change to be depend on interface IDBAccess 
{
    _dbAccess = dBAccess;
}
```

3. Provide a concrete implementation to `IDBAccess` in **program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDBAccess ,DBAccess>();
```

Finally, your program.cs will be look like this

```
using WebApi.Utilities;
    
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDBAccess ,DBAccess>();   //<<<< adding IDBAccess
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataAcess,DataAcess>();  //<<<<< adding IDataAcess
    
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer(); 
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
var app = builder.Build();  
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseSwagger();
   app.UseSwaggerUI();
}  
app.UseHttpsRedirection();   
app.UseAuthorization();   
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Comment: thanks for getting back to me I did add the builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataAcess,DataAcess>():  but the error.                       System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: WebApi.Utilities.IDataAcess Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: WebApi.Utilities.DataAccess: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApi.Utilities.DBAccess' while attempting to activate 'WebApi.Utilities.DataAcess'.)'

Comment: This error message say that you did not add `IDBAccess`  in the step 2 ...please read the answer and be sure from the step 2 ... Did you change `DataAcess` constructor to take `IDBAccess` not  `DBAccess` ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Are you referring to this part? if yes please could you elaborate a bit further.                                                                                                      public DataAcess(DBAccess dBAccess)
            {
                _dbAccess = dBAccess;
            }

Comment: Yes  I mean this, you should change it to `public DataAcess(IDBAccess  dBAccess) { _dbAccess = dBAccess; } `  you should use the interface `IDBAccess` not a concrete `DBAccess` and make sure that you add it in dependency container `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDBAccess ,DBAccess>();` in your program.cs

Comment: Thanks, I got it it's working now.